# Scrapy , how to change CONCURRENT_REQUESTS when is running？

Tags: scrapy

When the Scrapy is running, If speed is slow, I want to increase CONCURRENT_REQUESTS, if speed is fast, I want to reduce CONCURRENT_REQUESTS.

""I use self.custom_settings['CONCURRENT_REQUESTS'] = xxx, it's not working after running.""

Answer (score 0):

You can acheve this with scrapy AutoThrottle extension
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/2.5/topics/autothrottle.html

Updating settings on runtime is not possible on most of cases
[Scrapy/Git/Isse: Update spider settings during runtime #4196](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/4196)